# OpenLayers: WMS layer is not displayed

Tags: openlayers, wms

I'm trying to view a WMS layer with OpenLayers, but nothing is displayed. No error messages are shown in the console. Moreover, when I try to access the request string with the browser (Firefox), the map displays just fine. Here is the code.

```
<html>
<head><title>OpenLayers WMS test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script>
function init() {
var map = new OpenLayers.Map("maparea");
var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Maakuntakaava", "http://kartat.lounaispaikka.fi/wms/maakuntakaava",
            {'format':'png', 'layers':'mk_tiet', width:600, height:600,
            bbox:'224609.4426922916318290,6702129.8832325218245387,265885.8128110636025667,6720672.7353315912187099'},
            { projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3067"),
            units: "m",
            maxResolution: 1000,
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(224609.4426922916318290,6702129.8832325218245387,265885.8128110636025667,6720672.7353315912187099)});
map.addLayer(wms);
alert("Request string: " + wms.getFullRequestString());
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<h1>WMS test</h1>
<div id="maparea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map is created correctly, but you haven't zoomed to correct location yet, therefore you can't see anything. Use zoomToMaxExtent() to fit view:

```
map.addLayer(wms);
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```

Comment: That did the trick. I though I already tried this, but apparently I tried it on some other buggy version, so it did not work before. Thanks for the help!